# ext js 2.0 mimic igoogle interface

Tags: user-interface, extjs, igoogle

I would like to mimic the igoogle like interface in extjs.

Any starters ? or any alternatives ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by having a look to the 
[Portal Demo](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/portal/portal.html).

Comment: Hey that link was amazing thanks !! BTW does it work with EXT JS 2.0 as well ?

Comment: Yes, the sample was about the same with ExtJs 2.0, IIRC.